# How to determine which normal mode leads to the transition state (numerically)?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, reaction-coordinate

I would like to get the normal mode of vibration which leads to the transition state. Do you know any software for this problem? If no, could you offer an algorithm to generate it? By the way, is there any name for this vibration?